# Cant connect to Microsoft Sql Server with pymssql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

code:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='BD', user='user', password='pass', database='Test')
```

It returns:

```
pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason
```

**/etc/freetds/freetds.conf:**

```
[BD]
        host = ip (not in local)
        port = 1219
        tds version = 7.0
```

I try:

```
tsql -S BD -U user
```

It returns:

```
1Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    OS error 111
```

How to fix it? Does it mean, that I need to open ports on pc with Windows? How to make it?

Thanks.

Comment: Port 1219 is not the default port for SQL Server, are you sure it's correct? Some more information about your OS and SQL Server version would be useful, but you can check the basic connectivity: is  TCP/IP actually enabled for SQL Server, and can you connect from a Windows PC using the native client tools, e.g. sqlcmd.exe?

Comment: host of the db-server: windows 7, microsoft sql server 2000